# pymongo error when connecting to test:27017

Tags: python, ubuntu, mongodb

This is my code:

```
con = pymongo.Connection('test',27017)
```

and the error is:

```
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/桌面/test/mongo$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 3, in <module>
    con = pymongo.Connection('test',27017,slave_okay=True)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 352, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 576, in __find_master
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

Change 'test' to 'localhost'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is no mongod daemon running on test:27017.

Comment: How to start the daemon ??? I have the same problem... I'm running on windows... When i do

>>> import pymongo
>>> c = pymongo.Connection()

i get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    c = pymongo.Connection()
  File "E:\Softwares\installed\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\connection.py", line 370, in __init__
    self.__find_master()
  File "E:\Softwares\installed\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\connection.py", line 605, in __find_master
    raise AutoReconnect("could not find master/primary")
AutoReconnect: could not find master/primary